# sorting lists into lists of lists - Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

Im trying to write a function that takes in a list. e.g:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b']
```

and it should sort the list into a list of lists. e.g:

```
x = [['a','a'], ['b', 'b', 'b']]
```

struggling to find a starting point with this.

Comment: Create a dictionary with the entries as key and occurrence as key and populate a new list. However, extra memory is required.

Answer (score 0):

Use Counter from collections:

```
from collections import Counter

x = ["a", "b", "a", "b", "b"]
c = Counter(x)
res = []
for k, v in c.items():
    res.extend([(list(k * int(v)))])
print(res)
```

Returning:

```
[['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b']]
```

All in one, using a list comprehension:

```
print([[k,] * v for k, v in c.items()])
```